# Edit ListCell on MenuItem click

Tags: java, listview, javafx, textfield

I have been working on issue connected with the listcell editing. So far i have managed to create the ContextMenu for the ListCells but as i was progressing i encountered a problem. My whole idea was when i click, for example, the menu button Edit i want to edit the selected ListCell but not that kind of edit like the one the edit() method the listview provides. This one was different. I tried to create custom TextFieldListCell class so that i could validate the textfield with my own rules but i haven't succeeded.

For reference here is my code for the listview cell factory with menu items:

```
    languages.setEditable(true);
    languages.setCellFactory(ev -> {



        ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>();

        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem();
        editItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Edit \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));
        editItem.setOnAction(event -> {
            // The LanguageListCell class i want to put here...
        });

        MenuItem addItem = new MenuItem("Add language");
        addItem.setOnAction(event -> {
            String item = "";
            languages.getItems().add(item);
        });


        MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem();
        deleteItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Delete \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));
        deleteItem.setOnAction(event -> languages.getItems().remove(cell.getItem()));
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(addItem, editItem, deleteItem);

        cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());

        cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
            if (isNowEmpty) {
                cell.setContextMenu(null);
            } else {
                cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
            }
        });
        return cell ;
    });
```

and this is the code of my custom TextFieldListCell class:

```
    public class LanguageListCell extends ListCell<String> 
    {
    private TextField textField;

    public LanguageListCell() 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(getGraphic());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(getGraphic());
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }

    }
```

Comment: `setGraphic(getGraphic());` If you want to keep the graphic the same (i.e. continue to show the textfield after the edit has been canceled), this is the right thing to do. Also actually using your custom cell instead of `ListCell` would be a good idea... `ev.edit(cell.getIndex())` would be the appropriate code to make make the `ListView` edit the cell btw.

Comment: The thing with using edit() is that it calls the default TextFieldListCell class and i can't use my custom class. @fabian

Comment: If it's using the default `TextFieldListCell` you're not using a `cellValueFactory` returing your custom cell.

Comment: With the `cellFactory` you posted your cells shouldn't even be editable at all btw.

Comment: Yeah, now i get it. I will figure it out. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to know the solution to my problem here is the full code:

LanguageListCell class

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;


   public class LanguageListCell extends ListCell<String> 
   {
    private TextField textField;
    ListCell<String> cell = this;
    int i = 0;
    boolean manually_selected = false;


    public LanguageListCell(ListView<String> languages) 
    {

        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();


        cell.setEditable(true);



        MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem();
        editItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Edit \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));

        editItem.setOnAction(event -> {

            // The LanguageListCell class i want to put here...
            cell.startEdit();
        });

        MenuItem addItem = new MenuItem("Add language");

        addItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent> () {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ev)
            {


                i++;

                String lang = "New Language " + i;



                languages.getItems().add(lang);



                if(i == 10)
                {

                    addItem.setDisable(true);
                }
                languages.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                languages.getSelectionModel().select(languages.getItems().size() - 1);
                cell.setItem(languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

                manually_selected = true;



            }



        });


        MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem();
        deleteItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Delete \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));
        deleteItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent> () {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ev)
            {
                if(languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() - 1 > 0)
                {

                    if(i > 0)
                    {
                        i = (languages.getItems().size() - languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size()) - 1;
                    }
                    /*for(String lang: languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())
                    {
                        languages.getItems().remove(lang);

                    }*/
                    ArrayList<String> delete_data = new ArrayList<String>(languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
                    languages.getItems().removeAll(delete_data);

                }
                languages.getItems().remove(cell.getItem());
                if(i > 0) i = 0;
            }

        });

        contextMenu.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent e) {
                if(languages.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() - 1 > 0)
                {
                    editItem.setDisable(true);
                    addItem.setDisable(true);
                }
            }
         });

        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(addItem, editItem, deleteItem);

        cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());

        cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
            if (isNowEmpty) {
                cell.setContextMenu(null);
            } else {

                cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

            }
        });



    }

    public String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        cell.textProperty().unbind();
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
        textField.requestFocus();
    }



    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
        setGraphic(getGraphic());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        cell.textProperty().unbind();
        if (empty) {

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }

                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(getGraphic());
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    if(textField.getText().trim() != "" && textField.getText().trim().length() > 3)
                    {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                        setGraphic(null);
                        setGraphic(getGraphic());
                    }



                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

   }
```

LanguageCellFactory class

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import application.LanguageListCell;

public class LanguageCellFactory implements Callback<ListView<String>, 
ListCell<String>> {


@Override

public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> languages)
{
    return new LanguageListCell(languages);    
}

}
```

and the main class

```
languages.setEditable(true);

languages.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

languages.setCellFactory(new LanguageCellFactory());
```